# How to get temperature from DS18B20 sensor and display it on an Adafruit LEDbackpack (4x 7segments) using an Arduino Yun

Tags: arduino, temperature, arduino-yun, 1wire

I'm currently trying (for a few hours) to display the temperature got from a DS18B20 on my Adafruit LEDBackpack. But hen I try to init the display in the **setup** (*matrix.begin(0x070)*), the temperature returned by the sensor is always *-127*.

Could you please help me understand what I did wrong ?

#### Use cases

1. **Only temp sensor**: Temperature is correct
2. **Only screen**: Screen works as expected
3. **Both**: Screen works and displays what's expected BUT temperature returned is always -127.

#### Components:

- Adafruit LEDBackpack is using I2C so it's connected to SCL, SDA, 5v, GND
- Temp sensor is DS18B20 (1-Wire bus). It's connected to D#2, 5v, GND

#### Code

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <Bridge.h>
#include <Wire.h> // Enable this line if using Arduino Uno, Mega, etc.
#include "Adafruit_LEDBackpack.h"
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2
#define TEMP_DELAY 2000 // Request temp every two seconds

Adafruit_7segment matrix = Adafruit_7segment();

unsigned long time, lastTempCheck = 0;
float temp = 0;
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature. 
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

void setup(void)
{
  // start serial port
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Start up the library
  sensors.begin(); 
  matrix.begin(0x70); // If I comment this and do not use the matrix, the temperature is correct.
}

void loop(void)
{ 
  time = millis();

  if((time - lastTempCheck) > TEMP_DELAY){
    lastTempCheck = time;
    processTemp();
  }else { 
  matrix.print(100);
  matrix.writeDisplay();
  }
}

void processTemp(void){
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); // Send the command to get temperatures
  temp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.println(temp);
}
```

#### Schema

[image: Schema]

Comment: I'd suggest to connect DS18B20 in normal mode (with VCC wired to (+)) rather then in a parasite mode (VCC short-circuited with GND) and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried it but it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving each component its own power supply (i.e LED - 3V and sensor - 5v). Each pin can only output so much power to stop damage to the board. The LED may be drawing power from the sensor and the sensor may not have enough power to work correctly.

Comment: I tried to put the Led display on 3.3v and the temp sensor on 5v but it still gives me -127 :(

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit diagram shows a short-circut over the (+) and (-) pins (legs) of the DS18B20 - that short horizontal wire below the resisitor.  The value -127.0 indicates there is a problem with your temperature sensor too.

So if that's an actual problem (not just in the diagram), remove that wire to fix it.  Also, in your setup(), you may want to add some kind of check that your sensors are A-OK before looping:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS    2  // Arduino pin D2
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("setup() runs ...");

    sensors.begin();
    if (sensors.getDeviceCount() < 1)
    {
        Serial.println("DS18B20 Error - No sensors found");
    }
}

// ... rest of code
```